# Implementation of Delphi's TStringStream in C#

Tags: c#, delphi

How can I implement a StringStream class in C#, like Delphi's TStringStream class.

Here's how I would do it in Delphi:

```
var
    StringStream: TStringStream;
begin
    StringStream := TStringStream.Create('');
    StringStream.Write('stackoverflow', SizeOf('stackoverflow'));
end;
```

But in C# I don't have StringStream.

Comment: [`StringWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringwriter.aspx) ?

Comment: I think that the correctly is MemoryStream, but i dont know how use to write.

Comment: @Xyruleib you can use the following to write using `MemoryStream` : `MemoryStream.Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count);`. Have a great day :)

Comment: What are you trying to do? The code you posted gives no context. How much C# do you know? Have you read an introductory text book?

Comment: Do you realise that the code in the question is broken? `SizeOf('stackoverflow')` returns the size of a pointer, I guess. You mean `Length`. But if you are using `TStringStream` then you should use `WriteString`. If you are going to call `Write` then you are really just using a `TMemoryStream`. And in that case, you should be calling `WriteBuffer`. You are asking very poor questions. You are not thinking before asking questions. You would be more successful if you slowed down and thought about your problems.

Comment: Youch Xyruleib, dude, are you going to post every line of a Delphi program you've ever written, as a "how to do X in C#" question?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want either a

- `StringWriter` (which uses a `StringBuilder` behind the scenes)
- or a `StreamWriter` backed by a `MemoryStream`.

I don't know how Delphi does things, but in C#, strings are not the same thing as byte streams.

Comment: In Delphi neither, but the string data is. StringStream is similar to MemoryStream, only it allows you to easily fetch or set the data as a string.